# Gridbox: Shrink contents of grid row to make two equal height rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Assume I have a gridbox with 4 columns and 1 row. Parent container 1 & 2 are children of this gridbox. Parent container1 has a colspan of 3 and container2 has a colspan of 1 column. Both container have multiple child components, that are responsive and change size on window resize. Child 5 components has a table inside, that contains over 250+ records. The goal is to make this table scrollable, with perfectly equal content height of gridbox and without knowing any dimensions of parent or child containers.

So parent container2 has to be same height as parent container1, therefore something has to be done with child5

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/94cokdgu/47/)

**Expected layout:** (Same row height and scrollable table)

[image: Expected layout]

**Current layout:** (Unequal content height, table is not scrollable)

[image: Current layout]

I tried implementing flexbox for this scenario, but it seemed to make things harder. I also tried adding `display: flex` and `flex: flex-shrink` to the child5 container but with no results whatsoever.

I know I can programmatically take the height of container1 and calculate the needed height of child5 but  I feel like there's more elegant solution using CSS + I don't wanna add too much event listeners on window resize.

Would love to take a look at your suggestions.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply `display: flex` for your `.container1` class and use `flex` property:

```css
*, html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container1 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.container1 div {
  flex: 1;
}

.container2 {
  background: red;
}
.child, .child1, .child3, .child5 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray
}

.container1, .container2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
.child1, .child3 {
  padding: 40px 15px 40px 15px;
}
.child5 {
  overflow-Y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="container1">
      parent container 1
      <div class="child1">
        child 1
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        child 2
      </div>
      <div class="child3">
        child 3
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
      parent container 2
      <div class="child">
        child 4
      </div>
      <div class="child5">
        child 5
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>prop</th>
            <th>value</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```